# Сохранения массива в память

Tags: android

Как известно в андроиде мы можем сохранять булеаны, строки и числа в память. Но можем ли мы сохранять массивы? И иметь возможность загружать его при запуске приложения?

Comment: Что имеется ввиду сохранять? Куда сохранять? В БД, в SharedPreference, в файл? В любом случае можно продумать сохранение массива.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можем, используя [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html). Например, для массива целых:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();

b.putIntArray("key", a);
intent.putExtra("bundle", b);
```

Для более сложных типов данных, при условии сериализуемости:

```
b.putSerializable("key", data);
```

Comment: Не работал с Bundle, переменная будет сохранена в память? При перезапуске мы также все нормально сможем получить?

Comment: Этот метод используется, когда надо, например, посылать данные из одной активности в другую. Если же надо данные сохранять насовсем, то Bundle не подходит, тогда используют [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Comment: Shared Preferences не позволяет хранить массивы

Comment: Тогда сначала можно преобразовать массив в строку JSON, а уже потом сохранять с помощью putString. Обратно наоборот.

Comment: Пойдет. Как преобразовать массив в JSON cтроку?

Comment: Для этого используется прокси-массив [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html).

Comment: В случае с JSON можно огрести по производительности при более-менее крупных размерах массива.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ — сериализовать массив в файл, при запуске — десериализовать. Единственное условие — все элементы массива должны быть сериализуемы, конечно же (`implements Serializable`). По скорости — бинарной сериализации достаточно для большинства случаев, XML-сериализация уже заметно тормозит.

Как делается сериализация легко найти в гугле, например, [вот статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/java/60317/).

Comment: Кстати, нашёл багу на сайте - в предпросмотре &mdash; заменяется на тире, после публикации - отображается как есть.

Comment: Спасибо! Через некоторое время исправим.